# Add line plot to existing plot with zoo objects using ggplot2.zoo in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, zoo

I have time series climate data for 100 years. 
With base plot, I can plot the annual mean and then the 10 year mean on top with the following code:

```
plot(smoothprcp1yrs, col = "GREY")
lines(smoothprcp10yrs, col = "RED")
```

Using ggplot.zoo, the code to plot annual mean looks like:

```
ggplot(aes(x=Index,y=Value),data=fortify(smoothMaxtmp1yrs,melt=TRUE))+geom_line()
```

With `smoothMaxtmp1yrs` being my object.
**Is it possible to add another line on top using ggplot.zoo?**

### To make this reproducible, suppose my data looks like:

```
x.Date <- as.Date(paste(2003, 02, c(1, 3, 7, 9, 14), sep = "-"))
x <- zoo(rnorm(5), x.Date)
xlow <- x - runif(5)
xhigh <- x + runif(5)

z <- cbind(x, xlow, xhigh)

y.Date <- as.Date(paste(2003, 02, c(1, 3, 7, 9, 14), sep = "-"))
y <- zoo(rnorm(5), y.Date)
ylow <- y - runif(5)
yhigh <- y + runif(5)

a <- cbind(y, ylow, yhigh)
```

R base plot looks like:

```
plot(x)
lines(y, col = "red")
```

ggplot.zoo looks like:

```
ggplot(aes(x = Index, y = Value), data = fortify(x, melt = TRUE)) +
  geom_line() + xlab("Index") + ylab("x")
```

To plot y:

```
ggplot(aes(x = Index, y = Value), data = fortify(y, melt = TRUE)) +
  geom_line() + xlab("Index") + ylab("x")
```

**How can I add y on top of x?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To plot x and y together using ggplot graphics merge the zoo series and then use `autoplot.zoo`.  The argument `facet = NULL` tells it not to create a separate panel for each series.

```
library(zoo)
library(ggplot2)

autoplot(merge(x, y), facet = NULL) + ylab("Temperature")
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to combine (`rbind`) the output from `fortify` into a `data.frame` ahead of time:

```
df <- do.call("rbind", list(fortify(y, melt = TRUE), fortify(x, melt = TRUE)))
head(df)
#        Index Series      Value
# 1 2003-02-01      y -0.4688883
# 2 2003-02-03      y  1.2038141
# 3 2003-02-07      y  1.2194155
# 4 2003-02-09      y  0.9252823
# 5 2003-02-14      y  0.3187009
# 6 2003-02-01      x  0.2150564
```

Then you can pass `Series` to the `group` and `color` aesthetics:

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Index, y = Value)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Series, color = Series))
```

[image: Plot]